# show sqlite data in several window

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I want to know how can I use one data in several windows with python, Tkinter

this is my code for creating the database

```
def connect():
conn = sqlite3.connect("../database.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(
   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , name text , price INTEGER )"
)
conn.commit()
conn.close()

connect()
```

and this my code for get data and show :

```
 def clear_item_list():
    items.delete(0, END)

def fill_item_list(items):
    for item_ in items:
        items.insert(END, item_)

def item_list_view():
    clear_item_list()
    items = app.manager.data_1.view()
    fill_item_list(items)
```

I when I want to run project I get an error: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I don't know what to do if you can, please help me

Comment: Can you please show the full error traceback? Also you should learn how to read the traceback yourself. It is a very useful skill

Comment: [(1, 'Ghorme Sabzi', 24000)] this is print data

Comment: File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\user_sign_in.py", line 216, in user_screen
    item_list_view()
  File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\user_sign_in.py", line 49, in item_list_view
    fill_item_list(items)
  File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\user_sign_in.py", line 44, in fill_item_list
    items.insert(END, item_ )
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Should `items.insert(END, item_)` be `<name of Listbox instance>.insert(END, item_)` instead?